# React Navigation: The 'navigation' object hasn't been initialized yet

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am upgrading React Navigation library from 4.xx to 5 via  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/upgrading-from-4.x.html and https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/compatibility.html.

I am getting error:

```
NavigationDebug Error:  Error: The 'navigation' object hasn't been initialized yet. This might happen if you don't have a navigator mounted, or if the navigator hasn't finished mounting. You can ensure that all navigators have mounted after the callback to 'useEffect' is called in your root component. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html#handling-initialization for more details.
    at dispatch (BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:202)
    at Object.acc.<computed> [as navigate] (BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:245)
    at Object.navigate (NavigationService.ts:20)
    at SplashScreen.redirectUser (splash-screen.tsx:234)
    at SplashScreen.proxiedMethod (createPrototypeProxy.js:44)
    at _callee2$ (splash-screen.tsx:298)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:45)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:271)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:97)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:45)
```

while creating NavigationService (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html).

> index.js

```
let Init = ((props) => {

    enableScreens();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        isMountedRef.current = true;

        return () => isMountedRef.current = false;
    }, [])

    return (
        <NavigationContainer ref={navigationServiceRef}>
            <Provider {...stores}>
                    <App {...props}/>
            </Provider>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Init);
```

> NavigationService

```
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from '@react-navigation/compat';

import React from 'react';

export const isMountedRef = React.createRef();

export const navigationServiceRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
    if (isMountedRef.current && navigationServiceRef.current) {
        console.log("Navigation Should happen")
        try {
            navigationServiceRef.current.navigate("App", params);
        }catch(e){
            console.log("NavigationDebug Error: ", e)
        }
    } else {

    }
}

export default {
    navigate
};
```

Comment: *"... while creating NavigationService"* - are you sure that is when the error happens?  Did your console log show `"Navigation Should happen"`?

Answer (score 1):

*"... while creating NavigationService"* - are you sure that is when the error happens?  Did your console log show `"Navigation Should happen"`?

Perhaps elsewhere you have a "navigate" call, that is executed before the logic shown above.

In [your link - navigating without nav prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/) it suggests:

> *"import the RootNavigation"* and *"RootNavigation.navigate(...)"*

That is, anywhere that "navigate" might be called before navigator is ready, replace `navigate` with `RootNavigation.navigate`. (Where `RootNavigation` is your module that contains the code shown in question. See link for further details.)

Answer (score 0):

import :

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
```

then
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

```
<NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Homepage" component={Homepage}
            options={{
          title: 'Homepage',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#75C2F6',
          },
          headerTintColor: 'white',
        }} />

      <Stack.Screen name="Page_name_here" component={Page2}
        options={{
          title: 'Page_name_here',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#75C2F6',
          },
          headerTintColor: 'white',
        }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
```

Note : You can only wrap NavigationContainer with TailwindProvider and any custom Component. If you will wrap it will scrollView , then it will not work.

Answer (score -2):

For who is getting this error in a jest test. That's what I did...

```
const { getByTestId } = render(
        <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
          <ComponentHere {...props} />
        </NavigationContainer>
    );

const yourTextID = getByTestId('yourTextID');

setTimeout(() => {
      fireEvent.press(yourTextID);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).